# Build custom plugin to draft js

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I want to add @draft-js-plugins/mention but at the moment it's not possible since one of the dependencies of this package is immutable js that use a very old version thus cause an issue in my project since I'm using the newest version. It's not possible to downgrade at the moment and so I'm wondering what are my other options? Is it possible to integrate DraftJS with other libraries for this feature only? Is it possible to build a custom 'Mentioned' feature? How can I integrate it with Draft?
Any recommendations and examples will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`@draft-js-plugins` uses the same version of `immutable` as `draft-js`. So your problem would be draft-js which is using `immutable@3.7.4`.

See also: https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/pull/1710

Comment: Yes exactly. But I managed to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by using the 'react-draft-wysiwyg' package that was written on top of DraftJS and contains all the necessary plugins. A simple implementation that solves everything